# Xcode CI fails on various simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration

When running unit tests from Xcode all simulators pass the test.
When running the CI bot (on external OS X server) all builds are good but only one simulator will pass the tests all the other fail.
All simulators are installed on the OS X server and running tests from Xcode on OS X server it self also passes on all simulators.

The log files aren't giving clear direction what is going on here.

```
2015-02-04 06:12:27.349 Testing on device: <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7fa381c83460> {


SimDevice: SimDevice : Resizable iPad (291F00E2-1A85-47B4-81D6-F51431E53950) : state={ Shutdown } deviceType={ SimDeviceType : com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPad } runtime={ SimRuntime : 8.1 (12B411) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-1 }
}
2015-02-04 06:12:27.349 Initializing test infrastructure.
2015-02-04 06:12:37.987 Launch session started, setting a disallow-finish-token on the run operation.
2015-02-04 06:12:38.011 Adding console adaptor for test process.
2015-02-04 06:12:39.406 Creating the connection.
2015-02-04 06:12:39.406 Listening for proxy connection request from the test bundle (all platforms)
2015-02-04 06:12:39.406 Resuming the connection.
2015-02-04 06:12:39.406 Test connection requires daemon assistance.
2015-02-04 06:12:39.408 Checking test manager availability..., will wait up to 120s
2015-02-04 06:12:40.161 testmanagerd handled session request.
2015-02-04 06:12:40.161 Waiting for test process to check in..., will wait up to 120s
2015-02-04 06:12:44.828 Test operation failure: Unable to run app in Simulator
2015-02-04 06:12:44.828 _finishWithError:Error Domain=IDEUnitTestsOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=3 "Unable to run app in Simulator" UserInfo=0x7fa384c0aaa0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to run app in Simulator} didCancel: 1
```

Does anyone have had the same issues and a solution?

We're running latest version of Xcode 6 and OS X Server.